# I am trying to create popup div for one time load on whole website

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is popup-up div and it's working good. But it's load every time after I refresh the browser and what I want? I need this only one time when user open my website.

Any idea how to control this. FYI this is magento-2 popup.

```js
require(
  [
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
  ],
  function(
    $,
    modal
  ) {
    var options = {
      type: 'popup',
      responsive: true,
      innerScroll: true,
      //title: 'popup modal title',
      buttons: [{
        text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
        class: '',
        click: function() {
          this.closeModal();
        }
      }]
    };

    var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));

    $('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
  }
);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".actions").click(function() {
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup-modal">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <h1>Subscribe for Our <span>exclusive offer</span></h1>
  <p>Be the first to know about new arrivals exclusive offers and promotions</p>
  <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe')->setTemplate('subscribe.phtml')->toHtml();?>
</div>
```

Comment: You can store some data in localStorage or use beckEnd flag associated with user session. And check it in document.ready

Comment: check this one http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/jQuery-Plugin-To-Show-A-Popup-Only-Once-Per-Visitor-First-Visit-Popup.html

Answer (score 0):

Since normal JavaScript (actually NodeJS works server side) only handles client side operations (i.e. your browser), it cannot "remember" that a pop-up was shown once after a page reload. JavaScript need some kind of help for it. The point is that you do not need to care about the JavaScript part that much, but more about PHP in this case.

1.: You could save this information in a cookie, which could save the information if a pop-up was shown once. Only downside is that when you clear your browser cookies, the pop-up would come up again.

2.: You could you the MySQL Database to store this information permanently. Therefore you would need your own custom module though. Good examples can be found in the search.

My recommendation is to create your own module if you haven't already and extend the database table for customers with your information.

Hope this helps you to get in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Add cookie there are some functions related to CREATE ,READ and REMOVE cookie please find this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/7942/) or below snippet for more information.

I hope it'll help you

```js
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    function eraseCookie(name) {
        createCookie(name,"",-1);
    }

   $(function(){
 
      if(readCookie('OnlyONCE') == null)
      {
        $('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
        createCookie('OnlyONCE','true',7);
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cookie" style="display:none;">POP UP
    <a href="#" class="cookie-close">
    <span class="icon" onclick='onClose()'>X</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Curiousdev@ main issue is that how to implement this solution with code

Comment: using `$('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');` this line your model is popped up on page load right?

Comment: Curiousdev@ yes

Comment: see updated snippet just put `$('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');` in document.ready function if coockie is not null than it'll popped up otherwise not open

Comment: btw, magento2 has it's own built in javascript cookieHelper under lib